# Want to build updating status in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on rails ..

Want to add status feature, but having problem as we need to go create and edit page of each status. 
Want to know how can I do on the same page without leaving the page..

Comment: why you are not using ajax

Comment: you can try to use this gem https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place  here is a demo http://bipapp.herokuapp.com/

Comment: gone through it. But found that it helps to edit form. I want to update status like facebook.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like:

```
<%= form_for(@status, remote: true) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Check out the Rails [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for) on ajax forms.

You can render back with json like:

```
def create
  @status = Status.find(params[:id])


  respond_to do |format|
    if @status.update_attributes(status_attributes)
      format.html { redirect_to @status }
      format.js   {}
      format.json { render json: @status }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @status.errors }
    end
  end
```

I edited this to reflect updating a status.